# Dropdown selection value doesn't become a real value and work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a language dropdown and I try to alert the user to have to choose one language before doing anything further like languageOption can become a string and go into array. But it's not working and I don't understand why. I tried:

```
    alert("You didn't choose any language.");
    console.alert("You didn't choose any language.");
    console.log("You didn't choose any language.");
```

But they all don't work.

And I thought another way to solve this, which I make

```
<option value="1" selected>English (American)</option>
```

but then the value = "1" doesn't become the a value for variable 'languageOption'. So the arrays don't respond and don't know what to do when I see in console. I don't understand why the array is not responding.

Any help I would appreciate.
Below is my code:

```
<select id="languageSelection" style=display:none>
        <option value="">Choose a language</option>
        <option value="1">English (American)</option>
        <option value="2">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
        <option value="3">Japanese</option>
 </select>

    var audioSrc = "sound/"
    var audioType = ".wav";

    // default number of random question, if user this used the dropdown
    var default_numFollowUp = 4;
    // default delai (seconds) between random questions, if user this used the dropdown
    var default_secFollowUp = 10;

    // Create the audio element
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

    var endingArr = [];
    var runThroughArr = [];
    var randomArr = [];

    var languageOption = parseInt($("#languageSelection").val() );

    $("#languageSelection").on("change", function(){

        languageOption = $(this).val(); // Make languageOption value be string

        //if(languageOption.length==0){languageOption=1;}

        console.log("langugeOption is " + languageOption);

        console.log("Language changed to: "+ $(this).find("option").eq( $(this)[0].selectedIndex ).text() + " (Index: "+languageOption+")" );

        console.log(typeof(languageOption));  // Outputs string

        endingArr = [];
        runThroughArr = [];
        randomArr = [];

        if(languageOption === ""){
            alert("You didn't choose any language.");
            console.alert("You didn't choose any language.");
            console.log("You didn't choose any language.");
        }
        else if(languageOption === "1"){
            console.log("English");
            for(i = 0; i < intro_playList.length; i++){
                if(intro_playList[i].stage === "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList[i].runThrough){ runThroughArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
            }
        }
        else if (languageOption === "2"){
            console.log("Chinese");
            for(i = 0; i < intro_playList_chi.length; i++){
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].stage === "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].runThrough){ runThroughArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the value `intro_playlist`? the console message and the alert are displaying when I tried your code its just producing error that `intro_playlist is undefined`;

Comment: intro_playlist is bunch of audio files, same as intro_playList_chi with different properties such as "key": "2_how_old",
               "delayAfter": 6,
               "stage": "intro",
               "runThrough": true,
               "random": false.  When I try to see the languageOption, it's a string type.

Comment: when I try to select English or Chinese, it's working after I click Enter button.   If I don't click anything, then it doesn't go to default English. I wonder if it needs a user interaction for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the onchange function after loading the document. With jQuery, you can do it like this

```
var languageOption;
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    languageOption = $("#languageSelection").val();
    $("#languageSelection").on("change", function() {
         your code here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but it's still not working :( Any other idea? And if I do $(document).on("ready"), now matter what language I choose, it doesn't show anything. And when I try to select English or Chinese, it's working after I click Enter button. If I don't click anything, then it doesn't go to default English. I wonder if it needs a user interaction for that

Comment: Maybe it'll be better for you to upload your complete HTML and Javascript (maybe remove the irrelevant parts) and put the link in your question. Without the complete context, it will be difficult to debug the problem. I have used the concept I have mentioned multiple times, and I think the problem is laying somewhere else.